# __iadd__ behavior for a list which is an element of a tuple

Tags: python

```
numbers = ([1], [2], [3])
numbers[2] += [4, 5]
```

This code will raise an exception: `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment.`

I don't really understand how so. `+=` is syntactic sugar for `__iadd__` which executes the assignment all by itself, internally, i.e. without assigning in back to the list. So why would an exception emerge?

I know that `__iadd__` does not exist for tuples, and that in such case `__add__` would be called instead. `__add__` *does* assign the result back which would be a problem for a tuple as tuples are immutable.

But as far as I understand in case of `numbers[2] += [4, 5]` we call the `__iadd__` method for the list, not for the tuple. So why would the exception be raised?

Comment: [_"...if x is an instance of a class with an `__iadd__()` method, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`."_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) - In other words, it's **not** executed _"all by itself, internally"_. `numbers[2].__iadd__([4, 5])` succeeds (the list is mutable), then `numbers[2] = ...` fails (the tuple is not).